# Is it possible to use environment variables at install time with cpack?

Tags: windows, cmake, nsis, cpack

I'm trying to port some stuff at work over to cmake, and something that we do with our Windows installers (which currently use Inno Setup) does not appear to have a corollary in cmake/cpack. We have development libraries that get installed based on environment variables at installation time. So, the include files go to something like `"%DEV_INCLUDE_DIR%/include"` and the library files themselves go to something like `"%DEV_LIB_DIR%/lib"`, and the environment variables `DEV_INCLUDE_DIR` and `DEV_LIB_DIR` are in the environment on the box when the installer is run. So, what they were on the box that the installer was generated on is irrelevant.

However, cmake seems to want all of that configured at compile time. It uses the `install` target to generate the `package` target for cpack, and you use the `install` commands to add stuff to be installed with the installer. And it doesn't work right if I try and put environment variables in the path. If I try

```
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Include/" DESTINATION "%DEV_INCLUDE_DIR%/include")
```

then I end up with a `%DEV_INCLUDE_DIR%` folder in the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` when the package is installed with the NSIS installer, which definitely isn't what I want. I want it to replace `%DEV_INCLUDE_DIR%` with the value of that environment variable at install time. And I can't find any way to do that. Does anyone know how to do that or if it's even possible?

Truth be told, I don't even what an install prefix in this case (everything gets installed based on the environment variables), but cmake seems to be built around the idea that there is one, and I was hoping that the install prefix would just be ignored (or worst case, create an empty directory) if every `DESTINATION` in the `install` commands was an absolute directory, but it's not treating the environment variables as either environment variables or absolute directories. And all of the ways that I can think to tell cmake to treat it as an environment variable (e.g. `$ENV{DEV_INCLUDE_DIR}"`) would involve using the environment variable on the box that it's built on rather than the box that it's installed on. Is there any way to get cmake/cpack's install/package stuff to actually use the environment variables at installation time?

Comment: You can use $ENV{DEV_INCLUDEDIR} for the environment variable, but I think you will have to resort to a custom cmake-script, which runs at install-time and gets the user's environment variables